# Python multiprocessing: AttributeError: Can't pickle local object

Tags: python, docker, multiprocessing, pytest, integration-testing

I wrote a ChatOps bot for the collaboration tool Mattermost using [this framework](https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/tree/main/tests/integration_tests). Now I'm trying to write and run integration tests and I used their [examples](https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/tree/main/tests/integration_tests). By cloning the git repository you can run the tests by yourself. Their `docker-compose.yml` file will only work on a Linux machine. If you want to reproduce it on a Mac machine, you'll have to edit the `docker-compose.yml` to:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    container_name: "mattermost-bot-test"
    build: .
    command: ./mm/docker-entry.sh
    ports:
      - "8065:8065"
    extra_hosts:
      - "dockerhost:127.0.0.1"
```

After running the command `docker-compose up -d` Mattermost is available at `localhost:8065`. I only took one simple test from their project and copied it in `base-test.py`. You can see my source code [here](https://github.com/lucasscheepers/pyhelper/tree/master/tests/integration_tests). After starting the test by running the command `pytest --capture=no --log-cli-level=DEBUG .` it will return the following error: `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'start_bot.<locals>.run_bot'`. This error also shows up on the same test case in their project. The error happens at line 92 in the `utils.py` [file](https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/blob/main/tests/integration_tests/utils.py)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Without understanding anything about your problem, I would suggest looking at `multiprocessing_on_dill` https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing_on_dill/

Comment: What's not understandable at my problem? @DAdams You can reproduce the case very simple that's documented on their GitHub repository: https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/tree/main/tests/integration_tests

Comment: Sorry!  My comment was not a criticism of your question, which appears to be well written. I meant to say - I don't have the knowledge or experience to tackle the true cause of your issue. I did however run into generic multiprocessing pickle problems myself, and found `multiprocessing_on_dill` to almost always work for me.

Comment: Alright I'll look into it tomorrow. Hopefully someone else have more experience to tackle the cause of this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already went down this road but I think you might get past the pickling error by making run_bot take the bot that it does `bot.run()` with as an argument and then pass it to the process.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you meant. I've tried multiple things like passing `bot` as an argument but no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Action tab on that GitHub repository. Pytest seems to execute correctly (ignoring the exceptions on the webhook test)

Here is a recent run you can use to compare your environment set-up: https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/runs/4289644769?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: I have exact the same environment: Python 3.8.2 and Pytest 6.2.5. Also I'm running a different command stated in the question above and it returns the `pickle error`. When I try to use the command you're using: `pytest . -vv -n auto` it returns: `unrecognized arguments: -n auto`. Do you maybe know why? Also I posted this question six days ago and the tests runned 7 days ago, maybe that explains why it is now failing at my local machine?

Comment: Here is a run from 1hr ago: https://github.com/attzonko/mmpy_bot/runs/4356753006?check_suite_focus=true